# Differential equation, substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

By means of the substitute $y = v(x)Y (x)$, where $Y (x)$ is to be specified, solve the differential equation:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}+\dfrac{y}{x}=\dfrac{y^2}{x}$$

with $y=2$ at $x=1$

Anyone can solve it for me with explaining the steps please, I have no idea how to do it. Thank you very much

Comment: hint: separate the variables.  use partial fraction etc.

Comment: @abel. Your idea is very good but the OP seems to be asked to use $y=v(x)Y(x)$. I don't see what to do with the requirement. Cheers.

Comment: i don't get it. why would you want as a product? in fact $y = {2 \over 2 - e^{(x^2-1)/2}}$ is the solution and it does not seems to be the product of two simpler functions.

Answer (score 1):

> $$Y(x)=x$$

$\therefore y=vx\implies \dfrac{dy}{dx}=v+x\dfrac{dv}{dx}$

$\therefore\dfrac{dy}{dx}+\dfrac{y}{x}=\dfrac{y^2}{x}\\\implies 2v+x\dfrac{dv}{dx}=v^2x\\\implies \dfrac{dv}{dx}+2\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)v=v^2$

Which is in [Bernoulli's Form](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBernoulli_differential_equation&ei=sruFVLSqPJL-8QWBkoGIBw&usg=AFQjCNG281lYAj07g1Cf3Uel7KzjvjdAJQ&bvm=bv.80642063,d.dGc).

Comment: @Amzoti: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. It's now edited.

Answer (score -1):

$$
y' = v'Y + vY' = -\frac{vY}{x} + \frac{v^2Y^2}{x}
$$
if we re-write
$$
v'Y = -vY' -\frac{vY}{x} + \frac{v^2Y^2}{x} = -\left(Y' + \frac{Y}{x}\right)v + \frac{v^2Y^2}{x}
$$
set the brackets term to zero i.e.
$$
Y' = -\frac{Y}{x}\implies Y(x) = \frac{C}{x} 
$$
then we obtain
$$
v' = \frac{1}{Y}\frac{v^2Y^2}{x} = \frac{Y}{x}v^2 = \frac{C}{x^2} v^2
$$
which is separable.
Thus
$$
v = \frac{x}{C+C_1x}\implies y(x) = \frac{C}{C+C_1x}
$$
put it back into the equation we find
$$
y' +\frac{y}{x} = \frac{-C C_1}{\left(C+C_1x\right)^2} + \frac{C}{\left(C+C_1x\right)x} = \\
\frac{-C}{\left(C+C_1x\right)^2x}\left[C_1 x -\left(C+C_1x\right)\right] = \frac{C^2}{\left(C+C_1x\right)^2x} = \left(\frac{C}{\left(C+C_1x\right)}\right)^2\frac{1}{x} = \frac{y^2}{x}
$$

Comment: The unknown is $v$, $Y$ is a function of your choice.

Comment: then swap it round no?

Comment: Yes, that's the fix.

Comment: I also noticed another problem (namely the brackets was a silly expression) I fixed that also. cheers

Comment: But then you should specify $Y$.